# caffeine simulator: could not find file: WebSearch1.spc.bz2

Tags: settings, simulator, caffeine

I'm simulating in Caffeine's simulator a sequence of a several traces, of different formats.

However, when trying to run Umass storage traces I get errors, e.g.:

```
Could not find file: WebSearch2.spc.bz2
```

I guess that the problem dwells in some combination of the format, path, and filename.

E.g., when writing in the .conf file:

```
paths = ["lirs:loop.trace.gz"]
```

the format is "lirs", and indeed there's a file
\simulator\src\main\resources\com\github\benmanes\caffeine\cache\simulator\parser\lirs\loop.trace.gz

so this works fine.

Similarly, I created under \parser a sub-directory named "umass-storage", and downloaded there the file WebSearch2.spc.bz2, and then wrote in the .conf file:

`paths = ["umass-storage:WebSearch2.spc.bz2"]`

I tried also unzipping the file, and then use paths = ["umass-storage:WebSearch2.spc"]
as well as a few other combinations, but all of them give the error above.

Answer (score 1):

To discover the trace files automatically they have to be placed in the same package as its trace reader. In this case it would be `../parser/umass/storage`. However, since it is a large file you might not want to include it in you repository. Instead, you can specify the absolute path and keep the files in an external directory.

Comment: Hi Ben. I indeed tried that option as well before posting, but it doesn't work. May you please check whether it works in your machine?

Comment: @Itamarcohen Yes, it runs on my macbook with `paths = ["umass-storage:/Users/ben/Documents/traces/umass/WebSearch2.spc.bz2" ]`. I have not tried running on Windows (nor have a machine using that), so perhaps there is a minor bug if it fails there?

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to Ben I solved it, and got the tiny trick here.
For most traces it's enough to write merely the format name (which is also the directory name), e.g.:

```
paths = ["lirs:loop.trace.gz"]
```

However, umass traces include 2 sub-cases (storage / network). Hence it works (at least for me) only when stating the file's **full path**, e.g.,

```
paths = ["umass-storage:/Users/ben/Documents/traces/umass/WebSearch2.spc.bz2"
```